# changing attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to change **background** attribute using jquery. It's something like this

```
$('.insta-icon').css('background' ,'-webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%)');
```

If I put a simple color it works fine but with above gradient properties it's not working. Can anyone help.

Comment: Your css in invalid, try to apply same css in browser console and you will see browser will tells you is not valid. change `-webkit-radial-gradient` to `radial-gradient` and you are good to go

Answer (score 3):

I got this working using the `{ }` inside the function call. More importantly, I removed the `-webkit-` prefix, which was causing the `JavaScript` call to silently fail. Because `radial-gradient` [is supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_image_gradient_radial-gradient) in <s>93%</s> **96.72%** of browsers, the prefix can be ignored.

```js
$('.insta-icon').css({
  background: 'radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%)'
});
```

```css
.insta-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="insta-icon"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amg3dqLk/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your gradient code is wrong or not formatted. I have added the fiddle, hope it helps.

**N.B: Refer to [ColorZilla](https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Easiest way to get codes for gradient.**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.insta-icon').css({
    background: "-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%)" 
});
});
```

```css
.insta-icon{width:200px; height:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="insta-icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `radial-gradient` instead of `-webkit-radial-gradient`

and better if you use `toggleClass` instead of put `static values` into your code,

**Solution for your question**

```js
$('.insta-icon').css({
  'background': '-webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%)',
    'background': 'radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%)'

});
```

```html
<div class="insta-icon">
  <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Better Solution**

```js
function changeBackground() {

  $('.insta-icon').toggleClass('bg-primary bg-secondary');

}
```

```css
.bg-primary {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.bg-secondary {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeBackground();">Change Background</button>

<div class="insta-icon bg-primary">
  <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```